# read consecutive web pages with CefSharp

Tags: cefsharp

What should I do to be able read several consecutive pages from a web site? I am working with CefSharp WinForms and my problem is: In the loop I can get the source from the first page, but any other page gives only part of the source.
I use settings:

```
CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();
settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("enable-media-stream", "1");  
settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("no-proxy-server", "1");
settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("disable-web-security", "1");
settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("allow-file-access-from-files", "1");
Cef.Initialize(settings);
```

And use

```
public static Task LoadPageAsync(this IWebBrowser browser, string address = null)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

    EventHandler<LoadingStateChangedEventArgs> handler = null;
    handler = (sender, args) =>
    {
        //Wait for while page to finish loading not just the first frame
        if (!args.IsLoading)
        {
            browser.LoadingStateChanged -= handler;
            tcs.TrySetResult(true);
        }
    };

    browser.LoadingStateChanged += handler;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(address))
    {
        browser.Load(address);
    }
    return tcs.Task;
}
```